# Retrofit error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to solve this error but can't find any solution to solve my problem as I've tried all given links that's why I've to come here.

I'm trying to register user but can't. Please help me as this problem have already taken my whole day. Thanks in advance.

**My ApiClient.Java is here**

```
    public class ApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://IPAdress/foldername/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

   private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(){

        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
```

**User.Java class**

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("response")
private String Response;

@SerializedName("name")
private String Name;

public String getResponse() {
    return Response;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public static SessionManager sessionManager;

EditText Name, Email, Password;
Button btn_register, btn_login;

String name, email, password;

Boolean CheckEditText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);

    //if the user is already logged in we will directly start the Profile Fragment
    if (sessionManager.readLoginStatus()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileFragment.class));
        finish();
    }
    Name = findViewById(R.id.username);
    Email = findViewById(R.id.useremail);
    Password = findViewById(R.id.userpassword);
    btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    btn_register.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();
        if (CheckEditText) {
            registration();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
}

public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot() {

    name = Name.getText().toString().trim();
    email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
    password = Password.getText().toString().trim();

    // Checking whether EditText value is empty or not.
    // If any of EditText is empty then set variable value as False.
    // If any of EditText is filled then set variable value as True.
    CheckEditText = !TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password);
}


private void registration() {

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<User> call = apiInterface.performRegistration(name, email, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Response<User> response) {

            assert response.body() != null;
            switch (response.body().getResponse()) {
                case "ok":
                    RegisterActivity.sessionManager.displayToast("Registration Success...");
                    break;
                case "exist":
                    RegisterActivity.sessionManager.displayToast("User Already Exist...");
                    break;
                case "error":
                    RegisterActivity.sessionManager.displayToast("Something Went Wrong...");
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<User> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

[Here is JSON I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VXXW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this

```
public class MyResponse {
  @SerializedName("response")
  private String response;
  //Constructor
  //GET and SET
}
```

Then your service should return a `Call<MyResponse>` and then check the body as you are doing, it should work.

Comment: Do I just change that `Call<User>` to `Call<String>` ?

Comment: >Also would be good to know the json that you are expecting, and the data you are sending.
**I've updated the question with json data image**

Comment: by using your technique I created MyResponse clas and then change `Call<User>` to `Call<String>`. After this i got error on `switch (response.body().getResponse())` the part of `.getresponse` where it shows `incompatible types found required char, byte, short, int`

Comment: @MansoorMalik Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)